# Change dns-prefetch to preconnect for external enqueued resources

Tags: wp-head

At https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/37920 it defines the `wp_resource_hints()` function that was added with WordPress 4.6.

On that page it shows a section of the general-template.php file where the `wp_resource_hints()` function is defined, and there's also a function called `wp_resource_hints_scripts_styles()` which "Adds dns-prefetch for all scripts and styles enqueued from external hosts."

I would like to replace "dns-prefetch" with "preconnect" for all external enqueued scripts and styles. In other words, I would like the `wp_resource_hints_scripts_styles()` function to use "preconnect" somehow.

Is there a way I can modify the `wp_resource_hints()` function to achieve this?

I'm looking at the following part of the function, where "dns-prefetch" points to `wp_resource_hints_scripts_styles()`, and I'm wondering if that can be changed to use "preconnect" instead:

```
$hints = array(
  'dns-prefetch' => wp_resource_hints_scripts_styles(),
  'preconnect'   => array( 's.w.org' ),
  'prefetch'     => array(),
  'prerender'    => array(),
);
```

Apologies if I haven't worded this question in the clearest way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get this to work correctly, and also including the correct scheme (http or https) with each 'preconnect' link.

I made a copy of the `wp_dependencies_unique_hosts()` function (part of WordPress core) and modified it so it output both the scheme and host, and then incorporated it into the function that @jacob-peattie provided in his answer here. The resulting function works perfectly - as follows. (I go into further details about it here: [Change dns-prefetch to preconnect with correct protocol](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355670/change-dns-prefetch-to-preconnect-with-correct-protocol/355839))

```
function dns_prefetch_to_preconnect( $urls, $relation_type ) {
    global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;

    $unique_urls = array();

    foreach ( array( $wp_scripts, $wp_styles ) as $dependencies ) {
        if ( $dependencies instanceof WP_Dependencies && ! empty( $dependencies->queue ) ) {
            foreach ( $dependencies->queue as $handle ) {
                if ( ! isset( $dependencies->registered[ $handle ] ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $dependency = $dependencies->registered[ $handle ];
                $parsed     = wp_parse_url( $dependency->src );

                if ( ! empty( $parsed['host'] ) && ! in_array( $parsed['host'], $unique_urls ) && $parsed['host'] !== $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) {
                    $unique_urls[] = $parsed['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed['host'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( 'dns-prefetch' === $relation_type ) {
        $urls = [];
    }

    if ( 'preconnect' === $relation_type ) {
        $urls = $unique_urls;
    }

    return $urls;
}
add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'dns_prefetch_to_preconnect', 0, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter, `wp_resource_hints`, but it only filters each "relation type" (i.e. preconnect, dns-prefetch, etc.) individually, rather than the whole `$hints` array in your question. However, you could use the filter to empty the array for `dns-prefetch` and add `wp_resource_hints_scripts_styles()` to the `preconnect` array, like this:

```
add_filter(
    'wp_resource_hints',
    function( $urls, $relation_type ) {
        if ( 'dns-prefetch' === $relation_type ) {
            $urls = [];
        }

        if ( 'preconnect' === $relation_type ) {
            $urls = wp_dependencies_unique_hosts();
        }

        return $urls;
    },
    0,
    2
);
```

Note that I used a priority of `0`. This is to make sure that any URLs that were manually added to `dns-prefetch` by another plugin or theme aren't accidentally removed from all the lists, since we're only able to move the URLs from `wp_dependencies_unique_hosts()`.

Comment: Thanks so much - it's perfect, and nice and simple too! Works a treat.

Comment: Hi @jacob-peattie, I just noticed something odd with the function you provided here. Before using your function, my dns-prefetch links used protocol-relative URLs, like this:

`<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />`

But after enabling your function, the new preconnect links have 'http:' prepended to them - even though my site uses HTTPS:

`<link rel='preconnect' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com' />`

Any idea why, or how I can prevent this from happening with your function?

I'd prefer to the preconnect links to use HTTPS or at least protocol-relative URLs.